# RoboCopy and length of file paths

Tags: backup, file-management, robocopy

I'm using RoboCopy to back up between two hard drives.

I have noticed that the log is highlighting files that its copied to the destination folder even though they haven't changed since the last back up?

The new copies of this file are appearing in the source and destination folders and the file names have been changed from a standard name e.g. ParkFields.....xls to PARKF~1.xls. The next time I run RoboCopy it creates another copy of the original file and create an incremental increase in the file name e.g. PARKF~2.xls

Please can someone help to explain why RoboCopy is doing this and what can be done??

Comment: Which arguments are you using?

Comment: When you say haven't changed, are you opening the file to verify this?

Comment: /e /R:2 /W:2 /TS /FP /log /tee /eta. I know the files haven't been changed since RoboCopy has been run. They are a historical record of some previously completed work which no one would be using currently

Answer (score 0):

I'm wondering if you might want to use the /B switch, to copy in "backup" mode, if you only want to copy changed files.  Also look into /XO (exclude older files).

What you are seeing are the short names for the files.  I'd suspect that those files have long names equivalent to "copy of parkwhatever.xls", "copy(2) of parkwhatever.xls", etc.  Or, the total path+filename is too long, and it is defaulting to shortening the name automatically.